# What does r.successful() method do in python scipy ode solver?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the system of ODEs given by

```
y0' = y1^2

y1' = y0*y1
```

I have the following code to do it, however it only runs for 3 iterations.

```
from scipy import eye
from scipy.integrate import ode

y0, t0 = [10, 20],0

def f(t, y):

    f = [y[1]**2, y[0]*y[1]]
    return f


r = ode(f).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf')
r.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
t1 = 10
dt = 0.1
while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    print r.t, r.y
```

The result of running the code is

0.0604584108088 [  3.69320403e+08+0.j   3.69320403e+08+0.j]

However for a simpler system of equations, the code works perfectly. I checked that the r.successful() method is returning **false** when the iterations stop. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you have a bug in the code for the derivative `y0'` -- you have `y[1]*2` but it should be squared based on your ODEs, so `y[1]**2`. I don't know if this will solve your solution issue, but you should fix that first, then update the output for us.

Comment: @Mr.F thanks. I fixed it and this made things even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Added after updates below**

The problem turns out to be a floating point overflow issue. The system of ODEs grows very fast, and based on the initial values of 10 and 20, it quickly hits a point where the derivative calculations would involve numbers on the order of 10^308, which is the maximum representable value for double-precision floating point numbers.

By the time the original system is simulated to a timestep of about 0.060458, the y0 and y1 values are both around 10^154, meaning that, for example, calculating y1^2 for the next iteration of y0's derivative, will be right around 10^308.

If you make the initial conditions much smaller (but still larger than 1), you can see that the simulation is able to run for more time steps, but still eventually hits the point where this numerical overflow causes the same problem.

Unfortunately, the reported error from scipy is that the maximum steps are taken at a given iteration. Raising the maximum steps can't solve the overflow issue, which is what led me to discover it.

**Original Answer**

I believe the problem is that your timestep of `dt=0.1` is simply too large. The underlying numerical integrator is forced to take a number of iterations that it flags as too many (probably to alert you that it could be too inaccurate).

When I run your code as-is, I get the following warning:

```
In [80]: r.integrate(r.t + dt)
 ZVODE--  At current T (=R1), MXSTEP (=I1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching TOUT     
      In above message,  I1 =       500
      In above message,  R1 =  0.6045841080879D-01
/home/ely/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py:869: UserWarning: zvode: Excess work done on this call. (Perhaps wrong MF.)
  'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
```

and Googling for the "excess work done" part suggests it is indeed just too large of a step for this underlying integrator.

This is further corroborated by the time stamp at which the error occurs, something on the order of 0.06. Basically, the numerical integrator is getting from t0 = 0 to about 0.06 before hitting the maximum iterations it finds acceptable, which is only about 60% of the way to the first time step you requested, t0+dt = 0.1.

There is probably a way to configure the underlying integrator and tell it that you are happy with a large number of iterations, possibly with reduced accuracy, through some option specifiers passed in to `ode`. You'll have to look up the specific options available for your numerical integrator.

Reducing the step size is also an option. When I reduce the time step to `dt=0.001`, it seems to work with plausible values:

```
In [81]: dt = 0.001

In [82]: r = ode(f).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf').set_initial_value(y0, t0)

In [83]: r.integrate(r.t + dt)
Out[83]: array([ 10.40410373+0.j,  20.20509706+0.j])

In [84]: r.integrate(r.t + dt)
Out[84]: array([ 10.81670304+0.j,  20.42062500+0.j])

In [85]: r.integrate(r.t + dt)
Out[85]: array([ 11.23831377+0.j,  20.64704954+0.j])

In [86]: r.integrate(r.t + dt)
Out[86]: array([ 11.66950453+0.j,  20.88488262+0.j])

In [87]: r.integrate(r.t + dt)
Out[87]: array([ 12.11088028+0.j,  21.13467446+0.j])
```

This *seems* plausible, but of course you should continue debugging it to make sure this is suitable for your problem and there isn't an additional issue.

**Updated**

This doesn't appear to fully solve the problem, and when reaching the time step of around 0.060458, the method still has problems.

I also tried increasing the number of calls to the numerical integrator, and at this particular time step it still maxes out:

```
r = ode(f).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf', nsteps=10000)
```

with a set of warnings this time:

```
 ZVODE--  Warning: internal T (=R1) and H (=R2) are
       such that in the machine, T + H = T on the next step  
       (H = step size). solver will continue anyway
      In above,  R1 =  0.6045841351639D-01   R2 =  0.3076510569981D-17
 ZVODE--  Warning: internal T (=R1) and H (=R2) are
       such that in the machine, T + H = T on the next step  
       (H = step size). solver will continue anyway
      In above,  R1 =  0.6045841351639D-01   R2 =  0.3076510569981D-17
 ZVODE--  Above warning has been issued I1 times.  
       it will not be issued again for this problem
      In above message,  I1 =         2
 ZVODE--  At current T (=R1), MXSTEP (=I1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching TOUT     
      In above message,  I1 =     10000
      In above message,  R1 =  0.6045841351639D-01
/home/ely/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py:869: UserWarning: zvode: Excess work done on this call. (Perhaps wrong MF.)
  'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
```

So this requires further debugging, and maybe looking into whether there's some known property of your system that would cause numerical instability around this troublesome time value.

**More Updates**

So, if you just run the simulation from t=0 through to t=0.07 (so that it will choke at the t=0.06048 value) with dt=0.001, you can see how the system just explodes to very large values.

Here's all of the step output up to that point:

```
0.001 (10.4041037295+0j) (20.2050970562+0j)
0.002 (10.8167030429+0j) (20.4206250024+0j)
0.003 (11.2383137665+0j) (20.6470495441+0j)
0.004 (11.6695045326+0j) (20.8848826162+0j)
0.005 (12.1108802838+0j) (21.1346744591+0j)
0.006 (12.5630804127+0j) (21.3970117586+0j)
0.007 (13.0267874273+0j) (21.6725256647+0j)
0.008 (13.502734631+0j) (21.9618997688+0j)
0.009000000000000001 (13.9917114376+0j) (22.2658751074+0j)
0.010000000000000002 (14.4945672422+0j) (22.5852539012+0j)
0.011000000000000003 (15.0122198462+0j) (22.9209079717+0j)
0.012000000000000004 (15.5456551068+0j) (23.2737783851+0j)
0.013000000000000005 (16.0959417185+0j) (23.644890172+0j)
0.014000000000000005 (16.6642390877+0j) (24.0353601553+0j)
0.015000000000000006 (17.2517977739+0j) (24.446397397+0j)
0.016000000000000007 (17.8599896876+0j) (24.8793332583+0j)
0.017000000000000008 (18.4903063641+0j) (25.3356197052+0j)
0.01800000000000001 (19.1443722471+0j) (25.816842537+0j)
0.01900000000000001 (19.823978141+0j) (26.3247547557+0j)
0.02000000000000001 (20.5310803595+0j) (26.861275742+0j)
0.02100000000000001 (21.2678277394+0j) (27.4285182032+0j)
0.022000000000000013 (22.0366074843+0j) (28.0288339636+0j)
0.023000000000000013 (22.840039944+0j) (28.6648087645+0j)
0.024000000000000014 (23.681028251+0j) (29.3393118382+0j)
0.025000000000000015 (24.562806399+0j) (30.0555440188+0j)
0.026000000000000016 (25.4889935522+0j) (30.8170919659+0j)
0.027000000000000017 (26.4636383927+0j) (31.6279724531+0j)
0.028000000000000018 (27.4912813505+0j) (32.4926945713+0j)
0.02900000000000002 (28.577035653+0j) (33.4163407694+0j)
0.03000000000000002 (29.7266816328+0j) (34.404661152+0j)
0.03100000000000002 (30.9467842829+0j) (35.4641910143+0j)
0.03200000000000002 (32.2448296621+0j) (36.6023872192+0j)
0.03300000000000002 (33.6293921251+0j) (37.8277953977+0j)
0.03400000000000002 (35.1103399736+0j) (39.1502555779+0j)
0.035000000000000024 (36.6990898614+0j) (40.5811565676+0j)
0.036000000000000025 (38.4088780807+0j) (42.133707254+0j)
0.037000000000000026 (40.2552495245+0j) (43.8234256347+0j)
0.03800000000000003 (42.2565369308+0j) (45.6686178818+0j)
0.03900000000000003 (44.4344476937+0j) (47.6909650865+0j)
0.04000000000000003 (46.8149526813+0j) (49.916412137+0j)
0.04100000000000003 (49.4293307061+0j) (52.3762121964+0j)
0.04200000000000003 (52.315648486+0j) (55.1084066279+0j)
0.04300000000000003 (55.5207281611+0j) (58.1597924786+0j)
0.04400000000000003 (59.1026020953+0j) (61.5883773162+0j)
0.04500000000000003 (63.1344824954+0j) (65.4673490225+0j)
0.046000000000000034 (67.7098764857+0j) (69.8901904724+0j)
0.047000000000000035 (72.9499895239+0j) (74.9780829731+0j)
0.048000000000000036 (79.0149654384+0j) (80.8911464159+0j)
0.04900000000000004 (86.1208029476+0j) (87.8453557232+0j)
0.05000000000000004 (94.5658693689+0j) (96.1390548459+0j)
0.05100000000000004 (104.775315057+0j) (106.197370929+0j)
0.05200000000000004 (117.37502841+0j) (118.646168991+0j)
0.05300000000000004 (133.326297971+0j) (134.446714302+0j)
0.05400000000000004 (154.185877765+0j) (155.155738196+0j)
0.05500000000000004 (182.652227163+0j) (183.471676979+0j)
0.05600000000000004 (223.842467598+0j) (224.511629152+0j)
0.057000000000000044 (288.795900995+0j) (289.314873884+0j)
0.058000000000000045 (406.509437688+0j) (406.878298615+0j)
0.059000000000000045 (685.510973286+0j) (685.729775797+0j)
0.060000000000000046 (2181.3277524+0j) (2181.39652612+0j)
 ZVODE--  Warning: internal T (=R1) and H (=R2) are
       such that in the machine, T + H = T on the next step  
       (H = step size). solver will continue anyway
      In above,  R1 =  0.6045841351639D-01   R2 =  0.3076510569981D-17
 ZVODE--  Warning: internal T (=R1) and H (=R2) are
       such that in the machine, T + H = T on the next step  
       (H = step size). solver will continue anyway
      In above,  R1 =  0.6045841351639D-01   R2 =  0.3076510569981D-17
 ZVODE--  Above warning has been issued I1 times.  
       it will not be issued again for this problem
      In above message,  I1 =         2
 ZVODE--  At current T (=R1), MXSTEP (=I1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching TOUT     
      In above message,  I1 =     10000
      In above message,  R1 =  0.6045841351639D-01
/home/ely/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py:869: UserWarning: zvode: Excess work done on this call. (Perhaps wrong MF.)
  'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
0.06045841351638869 (1.34078079299e+154+0j) (1.34078079299e+154+0j)
```

So in the final case, you have `y0` and `y1` both at values of around 1.34 * 10^154 ... and on the next pass, the derivative terms will involve *squaring* this, which will be on the order of 10^308 ...

[10^308 happens to be the upper limit of representable numbers with double-precision floating point values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), so in the end it just seems that the magnitude of this solution based on your initial conditions grows extremely large too quickly, and somewhere internally the numerical integrator is having an overflow error, but it gets reported as an error having to do with exceeding the maximum number of per-step iterations.

If I try it with very tiny initial conditions, we see that it can run longer before the explosive growth causes a problem. I use initial values of y0 = 1 and y1 = 1.0001, and the same 500-iteration limit as in your original example.

```
0.9870000000000008 (77.4338433531+0j) (77.4338446447+0j)
0.9880000000000008 (83.9331879624+0j) (83.933189154+0j)
0.9890000000000008 (91.6236395126+0j) (91.6236406042+0j)
0.9900000000000008 (100.865565584+0j) (100.865566576+0j)
0.9910000000000008 (112.180884639+0j) (112.18088553+0j)
0.9920000000000008 (126.355922435+0j) (126.355923227+0j)
0.9930000000000008 (144.631347901+0j) (144.631348593+0j)
0.9940000000000008 (169.087126366+0j) (169.087126958+0j)
0.9950000000000008 (203.496415039+0j) (203.49641553+0j)
0.9960000000000008 (255.488666872+0j) (255.488667264+0j)
0.9970000000000008 (343.165281568+0j) (343.165281859+0j)
0.9980000000000008 (522.457925774+0j) (522.457925966+0j)
0.9990000000000008 (1094.08254168+0j) (1094.08254177+0j)
 ZVODE--  At current T (=R1), MXSTEP (=I1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching TOUT     
      In above message,  I1 =       500
      In above message,  R1 =  0.9999139897339D+00
/home/ely/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py:869: UserWarning: zvode: Excess work done on this call. (Perhaps wrong MF.)
  'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
0.9999139897338809 (9.13004735748e+13+0j) (9.13004735748e+13+0j)
```

Here, it makes it all the way to t=0.9999139... before hitting that same blowup with the same values and the same precision error. (Note that we're only reaching about 9.13 * 10^13, because I set the max iterations back to 500. If you set it at 10000, you'll see the same 10^154 problem.)

So, basically, for the growth of the equation you're simulating, and the starting values you use, you exceed the precision capabilities very quickly, and unfortunately the integrator routine reports this with a somewhat uninformative error about how many iterations were taken on a single step.